# Why Won't the BG Colors Show Up?

Tags: html, css, colors, background, format

I don't know why my BG colors wont show up? Can you help? Also I am trying to make a nav menu without any video tutorials. Any tips on the CSS formatting?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #NavMenu{
                Width: 800px;
                Height: 100px;
                Margin: 0;
                Padding: 0;
                Background-Color: #333333;
            }
            #NavMenu Li{
                Position: Relative;
                Display: Inline-Block;
                Float: Left;
                Width: 200;
                Background-Color: #959595;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <UL class="NavMenu">
            <Li><a href="">Home</a></Li>
            <Li><a href="">Games</a>
                <UL>
                    <Li><a href="">New Game!</a></Li>
                    <Li><a href="">New Game!</a></Li>
                    <Li><a href="">New Game!</a></Li>
                </UL>
            </Li>
            <Li><a href="">Contact Us</a></Li>
            <Li><a href="">Copyright</a></Li>
        </UL>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: css is case sensitive. while html isn't, your browser may be "correcting" your mixed-case html into something that the case-sensitive CSS won't match against anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are saying class ( `<ul class="NavMenu">` ), but you use # selector ( `#NavMenu`), which stands for id. Change it to `.NavMenu`.